# In typescript how to base a type of two other types keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Imagine a function getValidation that takes some state and a corresponding schema to validate the state. An example:

```
type State = {
  selectedColor: string
  selectedSize: string
  selectedOptions?: Record<string, string>
}

type StateSchema = {
  selectedColor: {
    required: (val: any) => boolean
  }
  selectedSize: {
    required: (val: any) => boolean
  }
  selectedOptions?: Record<string, { required: (val: any) => boolean }>
}

const state: State = {
  selectedColor: '',
  selectedSize: 'small',
}

const schema: StateSchema  = {
  selectedColor: {
    required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
  },
  selectedSize: {
    required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
  }
}

const validation = getValidation(
  schema,
  state
)

// validation
{
  $isValid: false,
  $value: {
    selectedColor: '',
    selectedSize: 'small',
  }
  selectedColor: {
    $isValid: false,
    $value: '',
    $validations: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  selectedSize: {
    $isValid: true,
    $value: 'small',
    $validations: {
      required: true
    }
  },
}

const state2 = {
  selectedColor: '',
  selectedSize: 'small',
  selectedOptions: {
    fit: 'tight',
    length: ''
  }
}

const schema2 = {
  selectedColor: {
    required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
  },
  selectedSize: {
    required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
  },
  selectedOptions: {
    fit: {
      required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
    },
    length: {
      required: (val: any) => Boolean(val)
    }
  }
}

const validation2 = getValidation(
  schema2,
  state2
)

// validation2
{
  $isValid: false,
  $value: {
    selectedColor: '',
    selectedSize: 'small',
    selectedOptions: {
      fit: 'tight',
      length: ''
    }
  }
  selectedColor: {
    $isValid: false,
    $value: '',
    $validations: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  selectedSize: {
    $isValid: true,
    $value: 'small',
    $validations: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  selectedOptions: {
    $isValid: false,
    $value: {
      fit: 'tight',
      length: ''
    },
    fit: {
      $isValid: true,
      $value: 'tight',
      $validations: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    length: {
      $isValid: false,
      $value: '',
      $validations: {
        required: false
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Things to note about the above examples:

- The state can be any object a user defines
- The schema structure must match the state structure until the schema defines an object where all of the keys are functions that validate that point in the state.
- The result validation structure should match the state structure with a couple additions. $isValid and $value will be added for every level of the state object. Where the schema defines a validator object the corresponding validator keys should be added to a $validations key.

How do you write a generic type or interface for a schema like this that depends on the structure of another type (in this case state)?

How would you write a generic type or interface of the resulting validation from getValidation which depends on both the structure of the state and schema types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't sure exactly what you mean't by "any object a user defines" in your question because TypeScript typings only apply a compile time and not at runtime so if the user provides these values at runtime only you'd need to use another approach.

I'm assuming in this answer that the user is either a developer using your framework or that you'll be codifying the user's required structure as TypeScript.

You can put together something like the below using:

- [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)
- [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types)

Note the I've ignored arrays here and I swapped your options from a Record to a plain object in the `State` type but it should work the same.

```js
type SchemaEntry<T> = ObjectSchemaEntry<T> | PrimativeSchemaEntry<T>;

type PrimativeSchemaEntry<T> = {
  [validationName: string]: (val: T) => boolean;
}

type ObjectSchemaEntry<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: SchemaEntry<T[P]>;
}

type Schema<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: SchemaEntry<T[P]>;
}

type ValidationResultEntry<T, S> = 
  S extends ObjectSchemaEntry<T> ? ObjectValidationResultEntry<T, S> : 
  S extends PrimativeSchemaEntry<T> ? PrimativeValidationResultEntry<T, S> : 
  never;

type PrimativeValidationResultEntry<T, S extends PrimativeSchemaEntry<T>> = {
  $isValid: boolean;
  $value: T;
  $validations: {
    [P in keyof S]: boolean;
  };
};

type ObjectValidationResultEntry<T, S extends ObjectSchemaEntry<T>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ValidationResultEntry<T[P], S[P]>;
} & {
  $isValid: boolean;
  $value: T;
};

type ValidationResult<T, S extends Schema<T>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ValidationResultEntry<T[P], S[P]>;
} & {
  $isValid: boolean;
  $value: T;
};

function inferStateTypeFrom<T>() {
  return <S extends T>(state: S): S => state;
}

function inferSchemaTypeFrom<T>() {
  return <S extends Schema<T>>(schema: S): S => schema;
}
```

You can then use it like this...

```js
type State = {
  selectedColor: string
  selectedSize: string
  selectedOptions?: { [key: string]: string }
}

const state = inferStateTypeFrom<State>()({
  selectedColor: '',
  selectedSize: 'small',
  selectedOptions: {
    fit: 'tight',
    length: ''
  }
});

const schema = inferSchemaTypeFrom<typeof state>()({
  selectedColor: {
    required: (val) => Boolean(val)
  },
  selectedSize: {
    required: (val) => Boolean(val)
  },
  selectedOptions: {
    fit: {
      foo: (val) => Boolean(val)
    },
    length: {
      bar: (val) => Boolean(val)
    }
  }
});

const result: ValidationResult<typeof state, typeof schema> = {
  $isValid: false,
  $value: {
    selectedColor: '',
    selectedSize: 'small',
    selectedOptions: {
      fit: '',
      length: ''
    }
  },
  selectedColor: {
    $isValid: false,
    $value: '',
    $validations: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  selectedSize: {
    $isValid: true,
    $value: 'small',
    $validations: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  selectedOptions: {
    $isValid: false,
    $value: {
      fit: '',
      length: ''
    },
    fit: {
      $isValid: true,
      $value: '',
      $validations: {
        foo: true
      }
    },
    length: {
      $isValid: false,
      $value: '',
      $validations: {
        bar: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The special sauce is in the `infer*` functions and using `typeof variable`. Because the type information from the `State` and the generic schema stuff is incomplete we need to use the inferred types of the actual state and schema objects to make type checking work correctly. This is complicated by us wanting an inferred type which derives from some known type i.e. State and Schema and that's where the `infer*` functions come into play. They don't actually do anything other than make TypeScript infer the type because we don't provide the generic parameter for the inner function.

Inferring the type of `state` and then inferring the type of `schema` based on that with `typeof state` then allows us to set up the result type as `ValidationResult<typeof state, typeof schema>` which gives us full type safety.

If you put the above code into the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygYwBZQLYEMCiA7EAnMAHgBUA+GAXhmJigA8QpsATAZxgHsAjAKygRAwA-DADyvfiEQoMOfETIwAXDAAKeAJYYQGgG5RpaLLgIlSAbmChIsdVvQ79h2SYXkqAb2AwYAbV3oADYazA4aHNgAcuioUCqs+BrYAOYAuioAFAGBKsQAlJTkXBwcgVDo2JYAvlbg0GISAs7G8maUMF4+vqowSTAA1lBgHABm1OnwyEZypsTdqRbANdb1zW2e3n49fYPDY8QTzTMK84vLdbAAakEhYREASlCsAK6BIMckADTw7jCbcLQGEw2A0+E0pi5WooROIwSBrsFQjoHk9Xu9XF8fso-j4AfRGCx2HZtHoDBCWrNyCJiWF9AjbsjsI8Xm8PsRvnByCpNtgoPo8JYVrZNCS6TckeEmajWRj2fBAQSQTTHGSZBS3L9OjAACQaVj05gqYqlcqVTba7LPOLUSw+C3iu7YVgqLVdbbYAZDUbwCbGsoVW0wKrVQUXUGSA2O5lotkchXA9iwyRHWWkTWbbq9D27b0HFSRxnRmVQ+Yc07VGAAMg65r1BqNJX9ZrtlutxBDtRsMALkqLIExeKBhMmarM6bdWc9e3G+Ydhel6JLqlSZeXZyrNbtdfFDZNAfNrdyHeAI2e2AEkqzIygeDgIAcUGINgAYngOKgzBkClq8FAQM88A9QhB0VdgyAyBIHxUOA8mgwoYEgxhqisU9z0ZK8b2aJ9oFfd9P2-TZf3-QCYGA+NhzWMhSAg8loNg+UKHIVhyWQztVnvRh2i1VgoDKAQoGYABhUoODweJEhSTYeL4xhmDgDQAC9rQSTRJJ8aTJAE0QIEZVghBdPxdnE1S0mMpJkiDJYrAQCIEgQjjYCoJJr1vBzsKgXCPzvB9qLyDJuN4zShJEsSYAAcjCz4pMC-i5MU60wtYDBAkCSLopkrSdMlZ1Nx8GARg0EAVDCnRkiQEA0rymAyhSEAkGKsLNhqKo8kFGynUEZi1XaZzMPJdzPMIC5vUQqBfP89KguEwJRJdTYfF-ABHZ4NF-Q0YCyIICkYmAACFG1NTbAjyJqovUmLZPkpS5qqpaVrWzJsm28h9r3bAjpOnwqjOhCLsy3SbrygqityqqRhKR6tvg16mw++agx+nwauSOrAaqrh0FCj7oYOio4aqmovqWVrrNswRfxZEGexRSmhpsEaHO+Yaxi6oxxx1bdERUEYgh4n77UCK00d+jLgpm0KIsRkWgquhKkqCVKpY02LtIB0GgcKhqpaRpgUfq8LGoJ07Jti6bZvV3V9R3fLeagKWBaFg37eyBlsuFhaoGW1aBO5234cJhGTcu+Lhct+sYHwK1naCR3EuSxX4YF13bPdmA7u99bI6gf3jfO0XVbdi3OZCX3Aj5xPD3Vnxga1+Gddq-WIv9qWa6rjmra5iO8CjuudUryXe6TiUU7b6uIa7q1e4Dr6peR1G27D62ebLu3B-7yqqr7udC9dTeMdCrOp5zong2AIA) you can see the inferred types by mousing over the variable names and if you try changing names and types of things you'll see that you get compiler warnings. You should also get auto-complete suggestions when you start typing.

Comment: Very cool.  I'm seeing a typescript error on this line `type ValidationResultEntry<T, S> = T extends object
  ? ObjectValidationResultEntry<T, S>
  : PrimativeValidationResultEntry<T, S>`.   `ObjectValidationResultEntry<T, S>` - says Type 'S' does not satisfy the constraint 'ObjectSchemaEntry<T>'.ts(2344) and `PrimativeValidationResultEntry<T, S>` - Type 'S' does not satisfy the constraint 'PrimativeSchemaEntry<T>'.ts(2344)

Comment: ts config `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}`

Comment: Which TypeScript version?

Comment: It's version 3.4.5

Comment: A separate question about that same line I mentioned above.  There is a circular type reference there.  Is typescript allowing this because of the conditional operator?  That is, is the conditional operator not eagerly executed allowing the circular reference?

Comment: If I understand correctly this solution also assumes that we are only ever validating primitive values.  What I'm looking for is that at any point in the state hierarchy, the schema can define a set of validations.  For example, I may want to design a schema  like this...

Comment: ```const schema = inferSchemaTypeFrom<typeof state>()({
  selectedColor: {
    required: val => Boolean(val),
  },
  selectedSize: {
    required: val => Boolean(val),
  },
  selectedOptions: {
    required: val => Boolean(val),
  }
})```

Comment: Note that the schema is now validating the selectedOptions value as a whole and not just the primitive members.  Allowing this flexibility would allow users to define validations for whatever part of the state they want.

Comment: Have amended the definition of SchemaEntry - will now just allow an ObjectSchemaEntry or PrimativeSchemaEntry at any level. Could probably be more strict by also including a conditional but think this is what you're after.

Comment: Incredible.  I've been trying to figure this out for days.  I'm gonna have to spend some time figuring out how this even works piece by piece.  Thanks again